# When atom absorb energy, how does the nucleon know?

Tags: photons, momentum, conservation-laws, atomic-physics, ions

Imagine a photon hits a hydrogen ion and is absorbed, how do the nucleon of the hydrogen knows and start to accelerate? Any difference between this and hydrogen ion in a electric field?

Comment: Recall that there is a force between the electron(s) and nucleus of an atom.

Comment: @JonCuster: do u mean electromagnetic force between electrons and protons?

Comment: Yes, of course. The electrons and the nucleus exert force on each other, which holds them together. Try to move one, and the other will respond.

Comment: @JonCuster: thanks I now understand and just curious would a powerful electric field rip electron and proton off the hydrogen ion because each particle accelerates in the opposite direction?

Comment: Field ionization is indeed a thing.

Comment: @JonCuster:got it

Answer (score 0):

The hydrogen ion is just a proton (assuming we are taking about $\,^1H_1$ here).

The first process that you have described is not technically possible. See proof in the footnote before. The closest you can come is a Compton scattering which is just a fancy term for the process where a photon hits a proton and another photon is emitted with a different frequency while the proton's momentum and energy is changed as a result.

The second process has to be between two charged particles with the two exchanging virtual photons in the process.

The biggest difference is in the nature of particles involved. The former involves three particles --one incoming real photon, one proton, and one outgoing real photon. In the latter, you have one proton, one other charged particle of your choice, and some virtual photons.

#### Footnote:

We operate in a frame where the proton is initially at rest. Let's say that the incident photon has a momentum $p_{\nu}$. After the collision, the proton has a final momentum $p_p$. Now, conservation of momentum implies $p_{\nu} = p_p$. But conservation of energy implies $m_pc^2 + p_{\nu}c = \sqrt{m_p^2c^4 + p_p^2c^2}$. The two equations are not compatible with each other. Here $m_p$ is the mass of proton.

Comment: Hi if I hit hydrogen molecules, electrostatic force between my hand electrons and the hydrogen electron repel each other then what is pushing the nuclei of the hydrogen molecule?

Comment: The interaction between your hand and the molecules is much more complicated than that. Your hand also contains many other nucleons besides just the electrons. The simplest interaction will be to hit one nucleon with another and observe the repulsion as a pure EM interaction.

Comment: I just got the answer it is electromagnetic force, thanks for clarifying the diff processes.

Comment: No worries. Good to know. Sorry I misinterpreted your question.